# Why does io::copy require the reader and writer to both be mutable references?

Tags: rust, immutability, traits

Why does [`std::io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html) require that both the reader and writer arguments need to be passed as mutable references?

I can understand why the writer needs to be mutated in order to accommodate data being written to it, changing its internal state.

However, why must a reader also be flagged as a mutable reference? If I am only reading data, then wouldn't I just need a reference to a given type and not a mutable reference?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because `Read` types are, in general, one-shot: by reading from it, you *are* mutating it.

Consider standard input: you can only read from that once, so *something* must be changing.  When you read from a socket, you're almost certainly mutating an internal buffer used to account for the differences between the network packets you get, and how much data you want to read at any given moment.  How about reading from a `Chain`, which is used to concatenate readable things together; without mutation, it can't keep track of which one it's supposed to be reading from.

Sure, it's *possible* to have a `Read` type that doesn't need mutable access to perform a read, but that's not *universally* true, and because it's not universally true, the `Read` trait demands mutable access.

Comment: That is actually a spot-on crystal clear explanation. Thanks!